# OSMNX not working with no rate limit in /api/status response

Tags: python, osmnx, overpass-api

We are hosting an Overpass API instance in AWS. It is a pre-built AMI apparently with rate limiting disabled which is fine for our purposes because it's a private instance. But we believe OSMNX doesn't want to talk to it because the `/api/status` response doesn't include `X slots available now` and just goes into a retry loop. This is the `/api/status` response that we're getting:

```
Connected as: 1190172919
Current time: 2020-12-30T03:02:05Z
Rate limit: 0
Currently running queries (pid, space limit, time limit, start time):
```

The default public Overpass server at `http://overpass-api.de/api/status` works fine with OSMNX, and it's `/api/status` response looks like this:

```
Connected as: 1190172919
Current time: 2020-12-30T03:05:38Z
Rate limit: 2
2 slots available now.
Currently running queries (pid, space limit, time limit, start time):
```

We would really like to use our own private Overpass instance, and the AMI was a convenient way to do it, but is there any way around this issue in OSMNX or must the Overpass server be reconfigured somehow?

Thanks

Comment: OSMnx is designed to work with the response format of the main Overpass API instance. Any idea why your status endpoint response differs from the standard? Is it due to your rate limiting configuration? Can you change that to generate the same response format?

Comment: That's what we suspect, that the AMI configuration is not rate limited. Still waiting to hear from the maintainer of that AMI to see if we can turn that off, but I suspect it's a configuration option somewhere.

Comment: @gboeing it would be nice to have an option for OSMX to support a non-rate limited private installation for commercial users who aren't really supposed to use the public Overpass API. At least that's my understanding of the public rate limited server, that if you're going to be overusing it then you should have your own instance.

Answer (score 0):

As of OSMnx v1.1.1, you can now configure whether OSMnx should check the overpass server status endpoint for how long to pause before making the next request. That check is necessary if the server uses slot management, but the setting can (should) be disabled if you are running your own overpass instance without any rate limiting.